Приоритет записей sql
Как можно реализовать следующий сценарий:
Есть n строк в таблице, у них есть поле prioritet, оно числовое и может идти не по порядку (1,2,4,5,7..)
Строки сортируются по этому полю.
Какой конструкцией можно повысить приоритет одной записи, и соответственно понизить у другой (их)?
Чтобы было наглядней, представим таблицу, где мы выделяем строку, и стрелками (вниз/вверх перемещаем запись)

Пишем обновляющий запрос. Или переходим на связный список.

На этом поле есть ограничение уникальности (primary key или unique)?

Найти запись со следующим (предыдущим) приоритетом и обменяться с ней приоритетами. Ну или прямо брать нумерацию по порядку из таблицы интерфейса, в котором вы тянете запись, и целиком скидывать эту нумерацию в базу. Ну или хотя бы текущую страницу, где запись видна.
